# Is $p^2+q^2+r^2=3^k$ with primes $p,q,r$ solvable for every odd positive integer $k\ge 3\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, square-numbers

For the positive odd integers $3\le k\le 25$, the equation $$p^2+q^2+r^2=3^k$$ with primes $p,q,r$ is solvable. Here is one solution for every exponent , calculated with PARI/GP :

```
[3, 3, 3, 3]
[5, 7, 13, 5]
[7, 17, 43, 7]
[5, 83, 113, 9]
[23, 173, 383, 11]
[109, 859, 919, 13]
[7, 677, 3727, 15]
[5, 2053, 11177, 17]
[5, 5659, 33619, 19]
[29, 35999, 95731, 21]
[277, 47407, 303143, 23]
[19, 124231, 912061, 25]
```

> Does such a solution exist for every odd positive integer $k\ge 3\ $ ?

We can assume $p\le q\le r$, equality is allowed. Since $3^k\equiv 3\mod 8$ , a solution , if it exists , contains only odd primes and because of the divisibility by $3$, we can rule out prime $3$ as well except in the case $k=3$ ; either every summand or none must be disisible by $3$.

It is clear that evey power of $3$ is sum of three perfect squares, but it is unclear whether each square can be the square of a prime number.

I found multiple solutions for small exponents $k$, so there might be a solution for every $k\ge 3\ $.

Comment: Solution for $k=27$ : $$[406993, 532867, 2678807]$$

Comment: Solution for $k=29$ : $$[2086879, 3756001, 7082921]$$

Comment: Solution for $k=31$ : $$[4975013, 16000447, 18355063]$$

Comment: Very heuristicallly: Below $n$, there are about $\frac{\sqrt n}{2\ln n}$ odd prime-squares $p^2$. hence below $2n$ about $\frac n{8\ln^2n}$ numbers $p^2+q^2$, so the chance that $n=p^2+q^2$ is about $\frac1{16\ln^2n}$ - or if we already know that $n$ is "right" modulo $8$ and $3$, about $\frac3{2\ln^2n}$. Finally, we have $\frac{\sqrt n}{2\ln n}$ candidates of $r$ to try. It is quite likely that $n-r^2=p^2+q^2$ for at least one $r$.

Comment: Solution for $k=33$ : $$[8676119, 17236489, 72018671]$$

Comment: Solution for $k=35$ : $$[28489633, 116257693, 188955113]$$

Comment: Solution for $k=37$ : $$[352287451, 391498259, 415820359]$$

Comment: Solution for $k=39$ : $$[29147, 5245973, 2013089077]$$

Comment: Solution for $k=41$ : $$[28961, 4619179, 6039285971]$$

Comment: Solution for $k=43$ : $$[25913, 53955173, 18117782873]$$

Comment: Solution for $k=45$ : $$[57719, 436857221, 54351834029]$$

Comment: Solution for $k=47$ : $$[12411797107, 43940957323, 156537388253]$$

Comment: There exists another solution for $k=17$ :
$$[4241,7451,7459]$$
I mention this solution because it appears that in at least one of the solutions for an odd $k$, two of the primes among $p$, $q$ and $r$ end in the same last digit. However, the solution you provided for $k=17$ does not support this speculation, so I found another solution, and surprisingly, it does. But the solution for $k=5$ is possibly the only solution that does not support my speculation. And by the way, there also exists another solution for $k=7$ :
$$[17,23,37]$$ and for $k=9$ : $$[29, 41, 131]$$